# Grails Unit Test Buggy Dynamic Finder

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am in the process of writing unit tests for a service class.  This service class calls `MyDomain.findAllByIdNotInList`.  The issue I am facing is that grails does not recognize NotInList as a dynamic finder for a mocked domain.  I tried Metaclass-ing this functionality out, but was having issues with it.

Any creative ways for bypassing this short of turning the Unit Test into an Integration test?  I would like to avoid this for multiple reasons (time to run, Only our Unit tests run at build time, etc)

Also, it is possible my metaclassing is written poorly:

```
MyDomain.metaClass.findAllByIdNotInList = {ArrayList list ->
        return []
    }
```

Edit:  Using grails 1.3.7.

also tried

```
 MyDomain.metaClass.findAllByIdNotInList = {deflist ->
        return []
    }
```

Bug report here:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8593

Comment: Have you imported DomainClassUnitTestMixin? Please take a look at this if you haven't http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains

Comment: Mixins aren't applicable as I'm using 1.3.7.  The bug posted in the jira.grails.org link is specific to 1.3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sagar V's comment is correct you should be able to utilize all dynamic finders when a Domain is properly mocked.  If you're using a version of Grails before 2.0 you'd have to extend `GrailsUnitTestCase` and call `MockDomain(MyDomain)` before attempting to invoke the dynamic finders.  As an FYI your metaClassing is not written properly (in my opinion you should use the mocking framework to get your test working I'm providing the correct syntax so you can use  it properly in the future).

```
MyDomain.metaClass.'static'.findAllByIdNotInList = {defList ->
    []
}
```

When the method that you're overriding is `static` you need to add the `.'static'.` inbetween the `metaClass` and the method name.

Comment: I forgot to add the .static between the metaclass and method name.  The issue as indicated in the JIRA is that the dynamic finder for `...NotInList` is not generated correctly when calling `MockDomain` in 1.3.7.  The metaclassing is needed to get around this issue.